# Any reason to use (MFC) CList<T, T&> rather than CList<T, const T&>?

Tags: c++, mfc, clist

I've learned some guidelines that all told me pass a variable by reference should always use const, like `func(const T& a)`. And I know the second template parameter in `CList` is a `ARG_TYPE`. Like `CList::AddTail(ARG_TYPE item)` would use `ARG_TYPE` as its parameter type.

I saw the sample codes in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bxde0zae.aspx) shows me it uses the `non-const` Type as its second template argument. Any reasons to prefer this `non-const` Type as parameter type?

`CList<string, &string> a;` vs `CList<string, const &string> b;`

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The link you posted shows that it does use `const Type &` as the second template argument.

Comment: In general, don't take advice on const-correctness from MSDN. The MFC programmers were const-averse, probably for completely legitimate historical reasons, but it's just downright bad practice nowadays. Unfortunately, the MSDN documentation tends to carry over that bad practice, failing a new generation of developers. In C++, whenever you can use const, you should do so!

Comment: @EricZ The sample code is at bottom of the page, and it uses three variable definitions that shows how to start using CList.  CList<int,int> myIntList;
CList<CString,CString&> myStringList;
CList<MYTYPE,MYTYPE&> myTypeList;

Comment: Never always follow statements that use the words _always_ and _never_, except this one.  The best practice, as @cody mentioned, is to use `const` wherever you can/should.  That implies that you need to understand when you should and should not use it, along with recognizing those situations in code (`const` CAN be used for method/function parameters, class method signatures, method/function return values, auto variables, et. al.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programming C++ without const is like driving without the safety belt on.

1.It protects you from changing variables that aren't intended be changed,

2.It protects you from making accidental variable assignments

3.Accepting arguments by const reference gives you the efficiency of passing by reference with the safety of passing by value

At the same time, the compiler can generate more efficient code because it knows exactly what the state of the variable/function will be at all times. If you are writing tight C++ code, this is good.

Just for your reference I have read Inconveniences of const in this article, but its higly recommended to use const-correctness

http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Comment: I've been using `const` a lot more on auto variables.  It not just documents that this variable's value is an invariant, but ensures that I don't re-use or mis-use the variable (see #2).  If/when I do, I get a COMPILER error, which is the best time in the development cycle to detect errors (as compared to RUNTIME errors).